# How to get search result based on priority of a indexed field value(data) in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, search, indexing

Lets assume I am searching for a keyword 'datastructure' and we have 3 different books including keyword 'datastructure' which have 3 different binding style (eg. Paperback, Hardback and ebook) and ISBN for each binding style is different. 
If I am indexing each book separately then I got total 9 (3*3) index documents and all will come in search result.
Let's say I have priority for binding style : 1- Paperback, 2- Hardback, 3-ebook.
So only three result should come based on priority of binding style (Paperback of book-1, Paperback of Book-2, Paperback of Book-3). 
And if Paperback of Book-2 in not available then result should be (Paperback of book-1, Hardback of Book-2, Paperback of Book-3).

My index document is :

```
        "bindingStyle": "HBK3",
        "keywords": "V AMERICAN 30 ADOLESCENT PSYCHIATRY ANNALS SOCIETY",
        "subjectGroup": "Professional (DRM-Free)",
        "isbn": "9780881634624",
        "imprint": "Routledge",
        "edition": 1,
        "subjectGroupCode": "150",
        "originator": [
            {
                "role": "HG",
                "name": "Lois T. Flaherty",
                "id": 2808300
            }
        ],
        "title": "Adolescent Psychiatry, V. 30",
        "reviewsForExport": null,
        "features": null,
        "cpdClassification": false,
        "titleNotTokenized": false,
        "id": 74300,
        "recentBooks": true,
        "relatedBindings": [
            "9781138005921",
            "9780203837597"
        ],
        "sku": "ER9247",
        "publicationDate": 1191369600000,
        "backCoverCopy": "<P>Lois T Flaherty, M.D., is a child and adolescent psychiatrist on the teaching faculty of Harvard University and the University of Maryland School of Medicine. A past president of the American Society for Adolescent Psychiatry and a consultant to the Center for School Mental Health Assistance in Baltimore, Dr. Flaherty remains active in school-based mental health programs and community psychiatry.</P>",
        "hdclassification": false,
        "countryRestriction": [],
        "shortDescription": "The period of adolescence can be a time of great creativity, as new intellectual capacities emerge, and as the individual adolescent attempts to make sense out of inner and outer experience. Volume 30 of Adolescent Psychiatry addresses the ways in which adolescent experience is transmuted into ",
        "pdClassification": false,
        "bestSellerStatus": false,
        "application": "UBW",
        "series": [],
        "sortByPublicationDate": 1191369600000,
        "subtitle": "The Annals of the American Society for Adolescent Psychiatry",
        "gtLastUpdate": 1536932063000,
        "imprintCode": "IMPR",
        "isbn10": "088163462X",
        "category": [
            "SCBE0505",
            "SCBE0545"
        ],
        "inventoryStatusCode": [
            {
                "distributionCenterCode": "USNY",
                "inventoryStatusCode": "LFB"
            },
            {
                "distributionCenterCode": "LOC1",
                "inventoryStatusCode": "LFB"
            },
            {
                "distributionCenterCode": "SING",
                "inventoryStatusCode": "LFB"
            },
            {
                "distributionCenterCode": "USFL",
                "inventoryStatusCode": "LFB"
            },
            {
                "distributionCenterCode": "AUS",
                "inventoryStatusCode": "LFB"
            }
        ]
```

And search query I have written is :

````
   "query":{ 
      "bool":{ 
         "must":[ 

         ],
         "must_not":[ 
            { 
               "match":{ 
                  "countryRestriction":"US"
               }
            },
            { 
               "match":{ 
                  "inventoryStatusCode":"PLZ"
               }
            },
            { 
               "match":{ 
                  "imprintCode":"IMPGP"
               }
            }
         ],
         "should":[ 
            { 
               "query_string":{ 
                  "query":"Handbook of Bipolar Disorder",
                  "fields":[
                     "title",
                     "subtitle",
                     "isbn",
                     "isbn10",
                     "keywords"
                  ]
               }
            },
            { 
               "nested":{ 
                  "path":"originator",
                  "score_mode":"avg",
                  "query":{ 
                     "query_string":{ 
                        "query":"Handbook of Bipolar Disorder",
                        "fields":[ 
                           "originator.name",
                           "originator.role"
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            { 
               "nested":{ 
                  "path":"series",
                  "score_mode":"avg",
                  "query":{ 
                     "query_string":{ 
                        "query":"Handbook of Bipolar Disorder",
                        "fields":[ 
                           "series.series",
                           "series.seriesCode"
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "minimum_should_match": 1,
         "filter":[ 
            { 
               "range":{ 
                  "publicationDate":{ 
                     "gte":-1574400600000
                  }
               }
            },
            { 
               "range":{ 
                  "publicationDate":{ 
                     "lte":1597775400000
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "from":0,
   "size":10,
   "sort":[],
   "aggs":{ 

   }
}```

How can I apply priority on bindingStyle so that It will reject all lower priority documents for a Book.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If new field bindStyleId can be added for different binding style
ex Paperback:1, hardBack:2 and eBook:3. 
Problem can be resolved using [Field collapsing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-collapse.html).
Collapse returns top 1 sorted document per collapse key(group by)
`
Query

```
{
   "query": {
                ...... --> your query
            },
   "collapse" : {
                 "field" : "bindStyleId"-->new numeric Id for binding style to enable sort
                },
    "sort": ["bindStyleId"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it it very helpful.

Comment: Glad could be of help.